Converting maxpool with big kernels to equivalent stacks of maxpool with small kernels
I have a onnx model for Object Detection inspired from yolo which has some MaxPool layers like this:

I have to port this model to a hardware that supports only selected set of layers and parameters.
I can't use these kernel shapes as I can only go from 1x1 to 3x3. 4x4 is deemed not optimal but I can use it.
I tried substituting them with a stack of 3x3 kernels like this:

I miscalculated the output shapes in this image but I will fix that.
I don't understand how should I substitute these big kernel shapes with a set of smaller kernels so that the output is identical or similar to the original with big kernels so that the performance loss is minimal.
